# AWS PHP SDK Promise doesnt work

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk, aws-sdk

According to the ***promise*** feature:
[AWS PHP SDK V3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/promises.html)
one should create a promise and the run the "then" function.

My code:

```
$promise = $client->copyObjectAsync($params);
        $promise->then(function ($value) {
            echo "The promise was fulfilled with {$value}";
        }, function ($reason) {
            echo "The promise was rejected with {$reason}";
        });
```

but the promise doesnt run...(it stays in pending state)
Only when i run the "wait" method (which is blocking) then the promise is executed.
Do you have to use "wait" and if so why do i need async?

Comment: Do you mean `copyAsync` instead of `copyObjectAsync`? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_copyAsync

Comment: according to the docs i see its: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#copyobject ($client->copyObjectAsync([/* ... */]);

Comment: @DannyValariola did you find a way to make this work?