# Promise in AWS SDK for PHP not work and no error return

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, promise

I'm trying to use promise in SNS client (AWS SDK for PHP) but it not work.
This code (synchronous way) work right with function **createTopic**:

```
require 'aws/aws-autoloader.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Promise;
use Aws\Sns\SnsClient;

$client = new SnsClient([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'ap-northeast-1',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => 'xxx',
        'secret' => 'xxx',
    ],
]);
$result = $client->createTopic(['Name' => "test"]);
echo $result->get('TopicArn');
```

But when I want to use promise (asynchronous way) by use function **createTopicAsync** :

```
$result = $client->createTopicAsync(['Name' => "test"]);
$result->then(
    function ($value) {
        echo "The promise was fulfilled with {$value}";
    },
    function ($reason) {
        echo "The promise was rejected with {$reason}";
    }
);
```

It not work and nothing happened, no error return. 
Anyone that might know what can be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following line:

```
// Wait for the operation to complete
$result->wait();
```

So the complete block should look like

```
$result = $client->createTopicAsync(['Name' => "test"]);
$result->then(
    function ($value) {
        echo "The promise was fulfilled with {$value}";
    },
    function ($reason) {
        echo "The promise was rejected with {$reason}";
    }
);
// Wait for the operation to complete
$result->wait();
```

UPD: Obviously, it makes a little sense to use async call this way. But to answer your question: to get any result in your case, you should synchronously force your promise to complete as described above.

**UPD2:** Here you can see [an example of executing multiple async operations](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/859). Notice that you will have to call wait() anyway, no matter how many promises you have

Comment: Thank you. But wait() function is used to synchronously force a promise to complete. That isn't thing I want. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Then you should describe what exactly you want to achieve. If you going to make multiple async calls, you have to create a separate promise for each operation, and then wait for the set of promises to complete. So you will have to call wait() anyway.

Comment: Added an example of executing multiple async operations

Comment: Sorry. I have updated my question. I want to use Async with aws sdk for php but when use wait() function it isn't Async, is it?

Comment: AFAIK using async calls in php makes sense for example when you have to make multiple i/o operations simultaneously.  I.e. not calling an operation after previous one have completed, but calling all of them simultaneously. But after you made several async calls, you have to wait until all of them complete/fail anyway. In case you have only one operation, looks like there is no sense to use async call + wait, you can just use sync version of the function, "createTopic"

Comment: sync call make client blocked while it sends HTTP request. That why I want use promise. Same problem in there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898455/aws-php-sdk-promise-doesnt-work?rq=1

Comment: **edited** If you'd like client not to wait until the operation completes, i.e. to close connection to browser and continue processing on server side, then this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138374/close-a-connection-early) would be helpful. Looks like promises _can't_ help you in this case, use them in case you'd like to make multiple i/o operations in parallel, for example